# How to fix 'SQLite3.Programming Error: Incorrect number of bindings' in Python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to SELECT an 'ItemID' from a table WHERE 'OrderNo' is equal to user the user's input.
I'm doing this to create a report on how ever many items the customer has purchased

However, I keep getting the same error;

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ItemID FROM 'Order_Line' WHERE OrderNo=?", ordernum)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

This is what I tried;

```
customerID = int(input("Enter customer ID: "))
check_cid = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID=?"
cursor.execute(check_cid, [customerID])
check_val = cursor.fetchone()
if check_val:
    cname_query = "SELECT CustomerName FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID=?"
    cursor.execute(cname_query, [customerID])
    cname = cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()

    # All items customer has ordered and total quantity of each item ordered
    ordernum_query = "SELECT OrderNo FROM 'Order' WHERE CustomerID=?"
    cursor.execute(ordernum_query, [customerID])
    ordernum = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.commit()

    cursor.execute("SELECT ItemID FROM 'Order_Line' WHERE OrderNo=?", ordernum)
    itemid = cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()
    print(itemid)


    itemname_query = "SELECT ItemName FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID=?"
    cursor.execute(itemname_query, [itemid])
    itemname = cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()
    print(itemname)
```

I was hoping to create a list of all items they have ordered and the total quantity of each item ordered - but I'm totally clueless on how to achieve this (I was thinking of a dictionary but I'm not sure), any help would be appreciated on how to do this.

Comment: Apparently your `ordernum` contains more than one order number.

Comment: `ordernum` is a 2-dimensional list of all the order numbers returned from `ordernum_query`. It makes no sense use that as the parameter in the next query.

Comment: Why are you doing these as separate queries instead of one big join?

Comment: You don't need `connection.commit()` after `SELECT` queries. Only queries that modify the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ordernum` is a list of tuples containing all of the customer's order numbers. If you just want one order, you can index it.

Also, `itemid` is a tuple, you shouldn't put it into a list in the next query. Even when you query a single column, `fetchone()` will put it into a tuple.

```
if len(ordernum) > 0:
    cursor.execute("SELECT ItemID FROM 'Order_Line' WHERE OrderNo=?", ordernum[0])
    itemid = cursor.fetchone()
    print(itemid)

    itemname_query = "SELECT ItemName FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID=?"
    cursor.execute(itemname_query, itemid)
    itemname = cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()
    print(itemname)else:
    print("No orders for this customer")
```

But you can do this all in one query that joins all the tables:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderNo, ol.ItemID, i.ItemName
FROM customer AS c
JOIN Order AS o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN Order_Line AS ol ON ol.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
JOIN Inventory AS i ON i.ItemID = ol.ItemID
WHERE c.CustomerID = ?
LIMIT 1
```